# sparkR do not support RDD related APIs after version1.6.1?

Tags: r, apache-spark, rdd, sparkr

In the https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23213

See the developer's comments:
"

> o clarify we don’t support RDD in R.
>   Anything you access via SparkR::: is not supported, that include unionRDD, is not supported.
>   Check the spark doc , not find any statement about RDD supporting issue.

Q1: Any SparkR official doc link about this issue (support RDD/APIs or not)?

Q2: Is this a common case to support RDD APIs for SparkR (e.g `SparkR::: map`)? Only allow using dataframe related APIs now in SparkR?

Answer (score 1):

Maintainers answers and `:::` should be authoritative and official enough , but:

[SPARK-7230](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7230) *Make RDD API private in SparkR for Spark 1.4*

> The main points in that document that relate to this ticket are:
>
> - The RDD API requires knowledge of the distributed system and is pretty low level. This is not very suitable for a number of R users who are used to more high-level packages that work out of the box.
> - The RDD implementation in SparkR is not fully robust right now: we are missing features like spilling for aggregation, handling partitions which don't fit in memory etc. There are further limitations like lack of hashCode for non-native types etc. which might affect user experience.

Considering that:

- RDD API is slowly deprecated from all parts of Spark.
- Possible functions would be duplicates of `gapply` / `dapply` functionalities.
- SparkR development resources are already spread thin.
- If there was enough interest it wouldn't be removed from the beginning.

there is really no viable case for supporting RDDs in SparkR. Of course if you want to dedicate resources ( and some more or its equivalent in development ⏰) required to fix the internal bugs yourself, nobody will stop you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you please offer more info/discuss link  to support this "RDD API is slowly deprecated from all parts of Spark."

Comment: @Tony https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api But please avoid asking follow-up questions, especially of such open-ended kind. And since the answer arguably addressed your issue, kindly accept it